# Pretty print of nested stringified json in logs

Tags: json, bash, jq

I'm tailing some logs, and to be able to read them easier, I use jq (http://stedolan.github.io/jq/), but either it's missing something, or I don't know how to do what I need to do.

So all lines are json, and currently I'm doing:

```
tail -f /path/to/log | jq .
```

Issue is, sometimes, I have stuff like this (when logging http responses):

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "fi": "bo",
  "stream": "{\n  \"json\": \"asAString\"\n}"
}
```

And obviously, would like to end up with something like this:

```
{
  "foo": "bar",
  "fi": "bo",
  "stream": {
    "json": "asAString"
  }
}
```

Although we can assume in a first time I know the specific name of this fields that needs to be processed in a particular way, if you have an automated way to do that :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a nested object... it's a json string. It's already pretty printed as it should. You need to parse the string if that's what you want.

```
.stream |= fromjson
```

Comment: Perfect! I could not find that ><
I actually ended up doing `jq '. | .stream |= fromjson'`, and apparently it does what I need!

Comment: That extra `. |` is unnecessary, it does nothing.

Comment: Well it does for me. If I don't I get this: "jq: error: null only strings can be parsed"

Answer (score 0):

For me what worked is to take your json string and pipe it to jq using the -r (raw) flag. for example if you have a json object where the value is a long stringified log message like

```
{"message":"some long string with \"escaped characters \n"}
```

You take that input and pipe it to jq like  `| jq -r .message`